# Can I force xarray.open_dataset() to do a lazy load?

Tags: python, lazy-loading, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have a ~1 GB netcdf file on disk.  I think that xarray.open_dataset() should do a lazy load so that I can see the file metadata without reading the whole file into memory.  But, it takes a really long time (several minutes) to execute the following lines in Jupyter Lab.  Also, memory usage goes up by ~1.5 GB.

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = r'..\data\external\SMODE_PFC_Wavegliders_WHOI43.nc'
# I don't know why, but this seems to actually load the data set, instead of lazy loading
ds = xr.open_dataset(file)
```

I tried passing the option `cache=False`, but the behavior is the same.

Am I missing something?  Is this a bug?

(I do receive a warning that seems irrelevant:)

```
SerializationWarning: Unable to decode time axis into full numpy.datetime64 objects, continuing using cftime.datetime objects instead, reason: dates out of range
  dtype = _decode_cf_datetime_dtype(data, units, calendar, self.use_cftime)
```

Comment: Try adding `chunks={}` to your `open_dataset` call. This way you should be using `dask` to load the data lazily, which doesn't load any data until you request it

Comment: @Val Thanks for the suggestion to try ```chunks={}```.  Unfortunately it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: I think you need `parallel=True` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine gave me the answer: I needed to pass the option `decode_times=False`.  With this option, `xarray.open_dataset()` does lazy loading.  The error I was receiving about 'unable to decode times' was the clue.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me ...

Comment: I guess the reason why it worked also doesn't make sense to me, but part of the issue is that the way the time coordinate was defined.  The sampling interval was 20 Hz and the time origin was decades away, so decoding the times involved use of very large numbers.  There is an extended discussion of this on GitHub: [https://github.com/pydata/xarray/discussions/6284](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/discussions/6284)